# Youtube video won't load into webView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, youtube

I am trying to load my video into a webview.
When I use this link. It won't work.

http://www.youtube.com/v/066PWBKrh6k&autoplay=1

But when I try this link. It's the same video but the link is a little bit different. It won't work. Any idea what the problem can be?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=066PWBKrh6k&autoplay=1

Kind regards.

Comment: Did you mean to say that one of those links worked?

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa Yes the second one works. But the first one don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are linking to a flash file. IOS wont play flash. the /v/id path links to a swf for clarification, while the watch link is something IOS might have a handler for to accept standard youtube links but play them in the youtube app. What you really want is a straight url to a mp4 file / h264 which ios will happily play in it's media controls. Youtube will not give you this because the video isn't branded, the branding is an overlay of their flash / html5 player. Your best bet is to use the actual youtube javascript api to embed a html5 player, or at least something compatible with IOS. Or just link to an address IOS has a registered handler for.